How to change font size for superweapons readiness in classic C&C Generals (v.1.0 from 2003)?
My problem is that having too many nuclear bombs I can't see opponents' weapons readiness since they are overlapped by the panel with "mines", "airstrike", etc., so I am trying to make the text smaller.
I tried editing the INI.big file and changed the size to 8 (it was 10 initially) and this doesn't help (of course, keeping binary structure of the resource; space added after 8):
  SuperweaponCountdownNormalFont      = Arial
  SuperweaponCountdownNormalPointSize = 8 
  SuperweaponCountdownNormalBold      = No

  SuperweaponCountdownReadyFont       = Arial
  SuperweaponCountdownReadyPointSize  = 8 
  SuperweaponCountdownReadyBold       = Yes

This is the text that appears in red at top right corner of the screen.
At the same time if I save and load game the font suddenly (without my changes, in the initial version) drops to tiny one. The problem with saved version that it plays too fast and ignores game speed parameter, so I can't just save/load at the beginning.
Meanwhile changing other parameters like
  SuperweaponCountdownPosition        = X:0.98 Y:0.003

works just fine.
